# JQuery.Ajax() no WebForms sem método static

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, webforms

É possível executar um método void do codebehind sem eles ser static? Estou tendo retorno de erro 500 ao tentar.

Comment: Seu método  é um WebMethod? Como você está fazendo essa chamada?

Comment: resposta curta: Não. Motivo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463189/why-webmethod-declared-as-static

Comment: Mas por que você precisa que ele seja void? não utilizar um ou outro método web que executa esse e retorne qualquer coisa...